# Azure requests showing up in New Relic - /Jobs/InvokeTriggeredJobs

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, newrelic, azure-webjobs

I'm running an Azure Web Site using the Standard service and I am seeing some activity that I don't understand where it is coming from. I have New Relic setup to track my requests and I am seeing the following line as the most time consuming process on my website consistently and by a large margin (average run time for this transaction is 17.4 seconds).

```
/Jobs/InvokeTriggeredJob
```

This is showing up as a Web Transaction, however I'm not sure where it is coming from. My best guess is that it is triggering my scheduled Web Jobs. I currently have 4 scheduled web jobs and 3 continuous web jobs with the most often occurring web job running every 5 minutes. I see spikes in New Relic for long running web transactions that are occurring every 15 minutes so I have to assume this is related to my web jobs. I do have a Web Job that runs every 15 minutes.

1) I'm not sure what /Jobs/InvokeTriggeredJob is actually doing as I can't find any documentation on it.

2) If this is related to triggering my scheduled jobs, why is it taking so long to run?

If I try to browse during my Azure website during the 15 minutes interval that is causing the large spike, I notice significant lag on my website to the point where I occasionally get a 503 service unavailable error. This is causing my site to become almost unusable at this point. Any guidance on where to look for possible causes? I'm unfamiliar with how to diagnose these issues using Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are really several questions here. To answer the primary one, the http requests that you see are indeed related to the invocation of triggered WebJobs, probably coming from the Azure Scheduler is you set it up that way.

You can see details about this API on [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#invoke-a-triggered-job).

As for the secondary question, if you're seeing your WebJob invocation take longer than you expect, and affect the running site, it could be that you are running out of resources. To test this, try moving to the next VM size (e.g. Small to Medium) and see whether that helps.

Comment: Thanks this has got me on the right track. I had forgotten that I setup the Azure Scheduler to start some of my Web Jobs and switched to the cron files awhile back. So the cron jobs are starting all my scheduled web jobs but two of the web jobs also have a scheduler setup for them. So the scheduler kicks off but errors out because the job is already running. I can see a bunch of errors in my Azure Scheduler because of this. I also have a test site in the same VM as my production site with the same jobs. So they are doubling up. Switching to a Medium VM definitely alleviated the issue as well.

Comment: I also saw you mentioned in a post on the Azure Support Forums that Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration is meant only for Cloud Services and not for Web Apps. I wonder if this is part of my problem as I am using that extensively in all my Web Apps and Web Jobs. If that is the case then what should we be using in our Web Apps and Web Jobs to retrieve the App Settings stored in Azure?

Comment: Just use standard `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]`

Comment: Great, didn't realize that worked with Azure settings. Thanks David!